# $resource Custom Action Replaces my Scoped Variable with the Server Response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I am using a $resource with a custom action.

```
myApp.factory('User', [ '$resource', function($resource)
{
    return $resource('/QuantumServer/users/:id.json',
    {
        id : '@id'
    },

    {
        resetPassword :
        {
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/QuantumServer/users/:id/resetPassword.json'
        }
    });
} ]);
```

I can retrieve my User objects no problem.  The problem is that when I invoke the custom action, the value of my locally-scoped User object gets replaced with the server response.  This is a problem because the server response is `{ success : true }`, which causes my local object to loose all its field values.

```
$scope.resetPassword = function()
{
    $scope.userBeingEdited.$resetPassword(
    {}, function(value, responseHeaders)
    {
        alert('Password reset');

        // The value of $scope.userBeingEdited has been replaced with the
        // server response - how to stop this from happening?
    });
};
```

I know that the RESTful philosophy states that e.g. a POST to a resouce would update that resource (on the server) and then return a copy of the updated resource.  I undertand that this is how AngularJS $resouce.$save works.  But must it really apply to my custom actions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18665982/226513 states that simply adding `isArray : True` to the resetPassword custom action definition stops the server from overwriting the local object.  I haven't got this to work as it just causes a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 0):

This is one workaround that I'm aware of, which causes a *copy* of the object to be updated which we then discard.  Is this the most graceful way?

```
$scope.resetPassword = function()
{
    angular.copy($scope.userBeingEdited).$resetPassword(function(value, responseHeaders)
    {
        alert('Password reset');
    });
};
```